# asp.net mvc render multiple charts in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-charts

Question1:
How to render multiple charts in a single view? In a ABController, I have two methods
MethodA (which matches with view name, MethodA.aspx) and MethodB.

When I load MethodA.aspx, it renders a graph from ABController.MethodA and on the same view I want to display another graph which is from MethodB.

Question2: Not really a question, I need a suggestion. Which is graph is best suitable for this?

I want to display list of students who failed to attend classes (count/number).

```
Controller Methods:
public FileContentResult MethodA()
{

}

public FileContentResult MethodB()
{

}

View:
<img id="image1" src="/AB/MethodA" alt="" style="vertical-align:top" />

<img id="image1" src="/AB/MethodB" alt="" style="vertical-align:top" />
```

Comment: How are you rendering a chart? Are you generating a temporary image and saving it to disk, or do you have a controller action that generates a chart image directly?

Comment: I edited the main post and added details. pls take a look

Comment: Anyone? I am looking for solution

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code so far. What is the problem? Do you not know how to render and return images from controller actions?